# Swap values of two select boxes in select2 plugin Javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have created two select boxes each have different country names with flag images using select2 plugin and values are fetching from Database below is the code.

JS CODE

```
$(".currencyconverterselect").select2({
  templateResult: addflag,
  templateSelection: addflag
});

function addflag(opt) {
  if (!opt.id) {
    return opt.text;
  }
  var $opt = $(
    '<span><img src="./img/flags/' + $(opt.element).attr('data-country-code') + '.png" class="userPic" /> ' + $(opt.element).text() + '</span>'
  );
  return $opt;
};
```

HTML CODE

```
    <label style="color:white">Currency from</label>
              <select name="fromcurrency_cc" id="fromcurrency_cc" class="form-control charts_currency" style="width:100%" required="required">
                <?php
$sql = "SELECT fc.country_id,fc.code,fc.name,cc.country_code AS countrycode FROM fx_currency fc LEFT JOIN fx_country cc ON fc.country_id = cc.id ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if ($row['code'] == 'AED')
    { ?>
                <option data-country-code='<?php echo $row['countrycode']; ?>' value="<?php echo $row['code']; ?><?php echo $row['countrycode']; ?>" selected>
                  <?php echo $row['name']; ?>(
                  <?php echo $row['code']; ?> )</option>
                <?php } else { ?>

                <option data-country-code='<?php echo $row['countrycode']; ?>' value="<?php echo $row['code']; ?><?php echo $row['countrycode']; ?>">
                  <?php echo $row['name']; ?>(
                  <?php echo $row['code']; ?> )</option>

                <?php }}
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
                ?>
              </select>
```

I have also created a button below is the code

```
<a href="#" id="swapvalues_btn1" style="color:white" ><i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x"></i></a>
```

I want to swap the value of FROM currency to TO Currency and vice versa by clicking the button.

I have tried below code

```
$("#swapvalues_btn1").on('click', function() {
    var pickup = $('#fromcurrency_cc').val();
    $('#from').val($('#tocurrency').val());
    $('#to').val(pickup);

  });
```

Comment: the rest of ur markup would be interesting too, cause i can't spot '#from' and '#to' anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select2 will listen for the change event on the  that it is attached to. If you make any external changes that need to be reflected in Select2 (such as changing the value).

Just use below code

```
$("#swapvalues_btn1").on('click', function() {
      var fromcurrency =  $('#fromcurrency').val();
      var tocurrency = $('#tocurrency').val();
      $('#fromcurrency').val(tocurrency).trigger('change');
      $('#tocurrency').val(fromcurrency).trigger('change');
});
```

For More follow the link
https://select2.github.io/options.html#events